# Can a local Appium Inspector access my app on Sauce Storage?

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, appium, saucelabs

I develop automated tests for a mobile app. 
The test are developed locally by me and run regularly on SauceLabs. The app which is tested is uploaded to SauceStorage to automatically test the most recent version of the app.

My current problem is that I don't have access to the most recent .zip of the app. So far, a developer sent it to me regularly to create my tests locally. 
I need to find a way to either access SauceStorage locally, so I can access the most recent app version in my Appium Inspector. Or I need a way to download items which are on SauceStorage.

Can someone give me advice on how to handle this?